# can i call a function and render a component when doing a ternary operator in react's jsx?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
{isItCool ? (
    /* call function here */ <Pause />
  ) : (
    /* call function here */ <Play />
  )}
```

need to call a function while also render a component inside of a ternary operator, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call a function and render a component inside a ternary operator in React's JSX.

Here's an example

```
import React from 'react';

const YourComponent = () => {
  const isItGood = true; // Replace with your condition
  const isItCool = false; // Replace with your condition

  const yourFunction = () => {
    // Your function logic here
    console.log('Your function is called!');
  };

  return (
    <>
      {isItGood ? (
        isItCool ? (
          /* call function here */
          <>
            {yourFunction()} {/* Call the function */}
            <Pause /> {/* Render the component */}
          </>
        ) : (
          /* call function here */
          <>
            {yourFunction()} {/* Call the function */}
            <Play /> {/* Render the component */}
          </>
        )
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```